# Не предсказуемое поведение $http в Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, http, циклы

Есть такой код

```
    $http.get('articles/articles.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.articles = data;
    angular.forEach(data, function(article) {
        $scope.article = [];
        var url = 'articles/'+ article.year +'/' + article.mounth + '/articles' + article.titlemounth + '.json';
        console.log(url);
        $http.get(url).success(function(data){  
            console.log(url);
            $scope.article.push(data);
            data = '';
        });
    });
});
```

Вот вывод первого лога

```
articles/2016/april/articlesApril.json
articles/2016/may/articlesMay.json
articles/2016/jun/articlesJune.json
```

А вот второго

```
articles/2016/april/articlesApril.json
articles/2016/jun/articlesJune.json
articles/2016/may/articlesMay.json
```

Т.е http срабатывает не в том порядке в котором задумывалось. Подскажите пожалуйста что можно с этим сделать.

Comment: так как `$http` шлет асинхронные запросы, а логи выводятся в ответах, нельзя гарантировать в данном случае что ответы будут приходить в том же порядке, что были запросы

Comment: А не подскажешь как должен выглядеть цикл чтобы отправка запросов была в определенной последовательности и вывод тоже был в той же очередности?

Comment: кроме того, на каждой итерации цикла затирается значение _$scope.article_, то есть в любом случае в нем будет _только один_ ответ

Comment: здесь вопрос в том. что _действительно_ нужно: если запросы должны выполняться по очереди. то есть не слать следующий вопрос _до_ того как придет ответ от текущего, либо ответы должны сохранится в массив в том порядке в каком были посланы.

Comment: Ответы должны сохранится в массив в том порядке в каком были посланы, сейчас один раз из ~8 запросов, ответы в массив пишутся в произвольном порядке.

Comment: не в произвольном. а в том в котором вернулись

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При использовании *forEach* есть доступ к номеру текущего запроса, таким образом ответ надо просто положить по нужному индексу:

```
$scope.articles = [];
angular.forEach(data, function(article, index) {
    $scope.article = [];
    var url = 'articles/'+ article.year +'/' + article.mounth + '/articles' + article.titlemounth + '.json';
    console.log(url);
    $http.get(url).success(function(data){  
        console.log(url);
        $scope.article[index] = data;
    });
});
```

При этом порядок логов также произвольный, но вывод будет в том порядке, в каком слались.